# Как устроен RAIL - жизненный цикл приложения?

Tags: javascript, производительность

Привет.

Разбираюсь с браузерной рендеринговой оптимизацией по курсу *Udacity*. Есть такая штука, как жизненный цикл приложения. Это 4 составляющих - *Load*, *Idle*, *Animation*, *Responce* (*LIAR*, обычно называют *RAIL*). Запутался в этом деле.

1. сначала идет загрузка (*Load* - первый этап жизненного цикла приложения), надо уложиться в 1 секунду на этом этапе.
2. Потом идет простой, когда браузер ничего не считает (*Idle* - второй этап), на этом этапе можно подгрузить, например, картинки с наиболее посещаемых страниц данного сайта, чтобы они быстрее загружались. Этот этап может длиться около двух секунд - проходит пара секунд (человек оценивает то, что перед его глазами) перед тем, как человек что-то щелкать начинает на странице. На этом этапе надо разбить *Idle*-скрипты на куски по 50 миллисекунд для того, чтобы без тормозов отловить начало взаимодействия человека со страницей.
3. Как только начинается взаимодействие человека со страницей, *Idle*-скрипты прекращают свою  ПРЕДзагрузочную работу и уступают место другим скриптам, например, скриптам анимаций (*Animation* - третий этап). Пример - человек кнопку меню нажал, а кнопка анимируется. Скрипту анимации надо уложиться  в 10 миллисекунд в вычислениях, плюс 6 миллисекунд уходит на создание кадра браузером, итого, 16 миллисекунд на кадр дадут 60 кадров в секунду.

НЕ ПОНИМАЮ -почему 4-й этап жизненного цикла приложения  *Responce*  идет последним этапом ?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что это **не этапы**, это **аспекты** ([four distinct aspects](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail)), и они относятся больше к достижению хорошего UX, чем к техническим ограничениям/требованиям.

И они не про последовательные процессы. Они **не упорядочены**, они относятся к определённым видам взаимодействия пользователя с приложением. Каждый из этих аспектов в течение работы приложения встречается *больше одного раза*, и в разном порядке, и не только в процессе изначальной загрузки, но и во время работы после неё.

Это с тем же успехом мог быть *LAIR* (берлога). Но это не очень стыкуется с назначением этих аспектов производительности.

*RAIL*  (рельс, гладкий, как производительность) как название просто подходит лучше.

Comment: как load может встречаться больше одного раза? есть какая-то книга, где про это ОЧЕНЬ подробно написано? только статьи одни встречал, в том числе и на гугл.девелоперс, в них только вскользь рассказывается

Comment: @Dimon XHR же, ну. И аналоги.

Comment: мне не понятен idle аспект, как его использовать. написано, что можно предварительно что-то загрузить с тех страниц сайта, куда человек вероятнее всего пойдет после прочтения данной страницы. я никогда не сталкивался с предварительной загрузкой и со скриптами, которые могут работать в idle-периоде. если без него рассматривать, то мне понятно. например, я написал Пакмэна на джаваскрипте. игра в браузер загрузилась, чтобы не было большой задержки между нажатием кнопки и анимацией управляемого мной объекта-пакмана, разбил расчет траекторий джвижения противников на куски в одном игровом цикле.

Comment: не понимаю, зачем idle-скрипт надо дробить на куски по 50 миллисекунд

Comment: @Dimon "User isn't interacting with the page, but main thread should be available enough to handle the next user input." JS же однопоточен (не считая вебворкеров, которые сами по себе) и подвешивание на любом действии на >50мс может не дать вовремя среагировать на ввод пользователя или внешние события, нарушив R или L.

Comment: мне не понятна само число 50 мс. если 60 будет, то, думаю, картина особо не поменяется. если взять 16 мс для анимации, то понятно - 10 мс на расчет и 6 мс на работу самого браузера. если взять 100 мс на ответ, то тут тоже все понятно - число чисто условное, приняли потому, что "круглое". а вот с числом 50 мс при простое - не понятно

Comment: @Dimon прочитайте хотя бы страницу по ссылке для начала. 100мс круглое, но взято не просто так, там сказано, почему. 50мс, скорее всего, взято как половина от времени реакции: в худшем случае 50мс займёт idle, а на реакцию останется ещё 50мс. Все такие рекомендации надо воспринимать не "как есть", а "откуда растут", не привязываясь к конкретным цифрам: они всё равно грубые.